# Im trying to create formsets based off of a quantity that would be input by users when they select from a product list

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

First I created the product list (list is based off of a product model) and sent over the names of the products in a form via POST. The quantities and other product information are then saved into a different model with the session id.

From there I do a request.POST.getlist() and a query to get the quantities where the sessionid matches the current session and the name in the POST values sent over.
From there I want to print out formsets where extra would be equal to the quantity that the user put in for the quantity of that product.

I then would like to save that information in tables that are specific to the item that was chosen. This sounds like a switch case situation in PHP but no idea how to do this in django(I’m new to it) Any ideas of how to do this? I tried this with a for and if statements like this:

```
   for f in request.POST.getlist()
       If f == x
       query to get the quantity for x
       formset = form that saves to a table for x entries with extra being equal to  the quantity 
       elif f == y
       query to get the quantity for y
       formset = form that saves to a table for y entries with extra being equal to the quantity
```

It seems to me that this always only gave me the formset for Y instead of both x and y 
*I should note that there would be more arguments than just 2, but it simplifies the idea. Also i have researched this on the site, there is something similar but the chose answer isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go over the [QueryDict documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). Mainly the request.POST.getlist() function doesn't return all of the items in the dictionary. It returns all of the values of a specific key as a list so the declaration is getlist(key, default). 
So, you probably just need to specify the key that you're looking for. Depending on how this values are structured I'm not sure if you need a for loop.

Now, for the formset it depends how you're building this formsets. If you are just going to return a form that is going to get repeated n times then I would suggest to send the form as the original Model renders it and handle the repetition of such form with Java Script. When submitting the form just serialize the information and handle it accordingly on your view.